# What are the advantages of embedding SVG as an <img> element instead of as an <image> embedded in SVG?

Tags: html, svg, vector-graphics

Let's assume I have an SVG file here that is to be embedded in the HTML of a website (**not** inline!).

Obviously there are two common ways to do this:

1. Directly as `<img>` tag:

   ```html
   <img alt="" title="SVG Title" src="svgFile.svg" width="24" height="24" />
   ```
2. As `<image>` embedded in the SVG element:

   ```html
   <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
     <title>SVG Title</title>
     <image width="24" height="24" href="svgFile.svg" />
   </svg>
   ```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of the different possibilities?

I have tried both options, but have not noticed any obvious differences myself. Have I missed something?

Comment: @tacoshy Almost! My question is aimed at the technical difference between these two solutions. The accepted answer to the other question includes embedding as an inline element as a solution (which is not applicable in this case).